# Error while making a class which extends from an implemented class

Tags: java, class, antlr, implementation, extend

this is my first question, i've got a problem from a class that used to work just as it is, the problem came up when I modified the parent class which uses an implement, it throws first an illegal start of type, followed by many "semicolon missing errors and missing braces errors... any help please:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class stvisitor extends CodigoABaseVisitor <void> {
   //Tabla de simbolos o Variables
   Map <String,Integer> tabla= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   STGroup codigob = new STGroupFile("C:/Users/TulioH/Desktop/Antlr4ST/classes/codigoB.stg");

   @Override 
       public void visitId(CodigoAParser.IdContext ctx){
           String id=ctx.ID().getText();
           if(tabla.containsKey(id)){
               System.out.println("hola mundo");
               //Escribir id;
           }

               }
```

Comment: Capital V in void for `CodigoABaseVisitor<Void>` I believe

Comment: Also capital S in `stvisitor` if you want to play by Java's naming conventions (Classes are UpperCamelCase so probably v uppercase as well: `StVisitor` )

Comment: Thanks for the capital V, it solved the problem; and thanks for the advice for the UpperCamelCase, I'll revise the names :)